# How variability with different data densities could affect comparisons among environmental variables

Tags: dataset, frequency, variability

I have several sets of data continually measured and recorded by instruments. The periods of record are 30+ years and the frequency of measurement can be every 5, 10, 15, or 30 minutes (288, 144. 96, or 48 data points/day.) The measurement frequency varies, sometimes within a 24-hour period, sometimes at midnight. (I can provide a list of datetimes and the measurement frequency in that period if that would help.)

I've not before seen data sets like these so I've no experience analyzing them, and I'm not a professional statistician.

Is there a meaningful difference in variability by the number of data points in a day? That is, if I calculate variability for a day with data every 5 minutes would it be significantly different from one calculated every 30 minutes? Or, if a month has different collection frequencies would the variability be significantly different than if the entire month had data collected at the same frequency? My interest is in the environmental variability of water quality components relative to the receiving water body's discharge variability.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a professional statistician either so this is just my thoughts.  You ask:

> Is there a meaningful difference in variability by the number of data
> points in a day? That is, if I calculate variability for a day with
> data every 5 minutes would it be significantly different from one
> calculated every 30 minutes?

Well I start in on this thinking about three words there: "variability", "meaningful" and "significantly".

"Variability": the most widely used statistic for variability is variance/SD and that is affected by the number of observations hence the (n - 1) denominator in the estimate of the population variance/SD in working from sample data. So the answer is that there *is a difference* between working from 288 data points from data collected every five minutes *versus* working from 48 data points collected every 30 minutes but the slight bias difference is handled by that correction in computing the variance/SD.  There is another difference of course in that you have much more data so much more precise estimation (or much more statistical power) with 288 data points than with 48 and that may affect what you mean by "meaningfully" and "significantly".

However, what I've just said is for the typical "independent observations" model and you don't have independent observations, you have a times series so the data are unlikely to be independent but probably show serial correlation.  That moves us into territory that is beyond me.  However, I am sure you will really need to be careful to specify what you want to learn from the data much more precisely than you have so you need to say what you mean by variability (there are other statistics/indicators than variance/SD) and then exactly what you want to learn from your data. That touches your "meaningfully" and "significantly".

You could frame it within the null hypothesis testing framework, i.e. as a fully specified null defined in terms of your variables and the operations on them, and whether your alternative is directional and what alpha level you are going to use (the old, old .05 usually of course). That gets you to a fully formalised use of "significantly" in terms of "statistically significantly".

For most things I look at I find the estimation approach feels more informative ("meaningful"?) but that still needs specfication of exactly what statistic in your sample you are treating as a point estimate of the population value and then the process for getting a confidence interval around that.  If I have large enough samples I tend to favour bootstrapping to get the CI but I know just enough about time series to know that bootstrapping such data is not a trivial issue.

However, "meaningful" is a lovely word but I think it doesn't map easily into statistics and statistical maths (though Bayesian theory I think goes a long way to mapping that, but again, that's not my competence).

I hope this is some help.  I'd love to see others more expert than us helping with the time series issues.

Comment: You're correct that I was not sufficiently clear in how I asked my question. By variability I mean variance; perhaps sd. After I explore variances with the different time intervals I'll see if there are statistically significant differences, but the ecological significance could well be different. And, with environmental data the null hypothesis significant testing paradigm doesn't apply to observational data because there is neither treatment nor control as there are in experiments. Thanks for your response. It adds to my thoughts. Stay well.